# Get top n results partitioned by myField

Tags: solr, filter, grouping, partition

I need to be able to filter my solr results so that for each FieldA only the top n results ordered by FieldB are displayed.

Example:

Before applying filter:

```
+----------+----------+
|  FieldA  |  FieldB  |
+----------+----------+
|    1     |     1    |
|    1     |     2    |
|    1     |     3    |
|    1     |     4    |
|    2     |     1    |
|    2     |     2    |
|    2     |     3    |
|    3     |     1    |
|    3     |     2    |
+----------+----------+
```

I want to filter so that for each FieldA only the top 2 entries based on the highest values from FieldB are displayed:

```
+----------+----------+
|  FieldA  |  FieldB  |
+----------+----------+
|    1     |     3    |
|    1     |     4    |
|    2     |     2    |
|    2     |     3    |
|    3     |     1    |
|    3     |     2    |
+----------+----------+
```

The query might have other filters applied to it and I want this grouping to be applied after all the filters have been applied.

Result grouping (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) seemed to do just what I needed.

The problem with result grouping is that the returned count for total results / facets is the count of the results before applying the grouping. I need to have a count of the results with the grouping applied (basically I want the grouping to behave like a filter). After researching this, I found that SOLR doesn't currently support this - I can only get the total number of results or the number of groups returned.

Can I use a different approach to get what I need? (top results for Field + count of results matching the "top filter")

**Later Edit:**

I've tried different combinations / values for group.format and group.main. They flattened / changed the results format.

I've tried group.facet = true; The facet counts are now based on the groups returned; however, I need the facet counts to be based on the number of returned results (not the groups)

group.ngroups = true returns the number of groups; however, this doesn't help me since I need the number of rows return when the "group filter" is applied.

Comment: Have you tried the parameter `rows` ?

Comment: Doesn't `group.format=simple` also modify the facet counts? There's also `group.truncate`, but that seems to only support the first document in each group.

Comment: I've added extra information regarding group.format, group.main, group.facet in the initial post